# CSS: Mismatching fill-color when using inline SVG for cursor image

Tags: css, svg, colors

I'm using an inline SVG as a cursor image:

```
#someElement{
  cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' width='16px' height='16px' xml:space='preserve'%3E %3Ccircle cx='8' cy='8' r='8' fill='%23145afa' /%3E %3C/svg%3E") 8 8, auto;
}
```

The SVG's fill is set to `#145afa` (a light shade of blue). However, when testing this in Chrome and Firefox, the cursor's color does not match the color of other (regular HTML) elements on the page with a background-color set to the same hex-code. In Safari the colors match (as intended).

This snippet demonstrates the problem:

```css
html {
  cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' width='16px' height='16px' xml:space='preserve'%3E %3Ccircle cx='8' cy='8' r='8' fill='%23145afa' /%3E %3C/svg%3E") 8 8, auto;
}

#blue {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  text-align: center;

  background-color: #145afa;
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<div id="blue">
  <p>
    my background-color is #145afa
  </p>
</div>
```

How/Why does this happen? Since the hex-code in the inline SVG and the hex-code of the div's background is the same, shouldn't the colors match?

EDIT: Responding to a comment, here's a photo of the mismatching colors on my screen:

[image: Mismatching colors]

Comment: They do match. There's some antialiasing round the edge, is that what you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at the question. On my screen they do not match, unfortunately I can't screenshot it (cursor disappears when screenshotting on Mac OS). Which browser did you use to view the question/snippet?

Edit: I'll take a photo and append it to the question to show you how it looks on my screen.

Comment: Matches on Chrome on Windows. I do see a difference on Firefox on Mac. Firefox doesn't seem to have the antialiasing issue I saw on Chrome though.

Comment: Interesting. Haven't tested on Windows yet. Any idea what causes this?

Comment: Since the cursor is an image, perhaps Firefox is using the [display's colour profile](https://www.eizoglobal.com/library/management/web-color-management/)